# react checkbox: event.preventDefault() breaks onChange function - why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events, preventdefault, html-input

I have just found a stray `event.preventDefault()` that was breaking my checkboxes' `onChange` handler:

```
import { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      accepted: false
    }
  }

  changeChecked = (event) => {
    this.setState((state) => ({
      accepted : !state.accepted
    }));
    event.preventDefault(); // <- this very bad
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <input
        type="checkbox" 
        onChange={this.changeChecked}
        checked={this.state.accepted}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The resulting behaviour is a correctly updated state on first click, but the checkbox only changes to its 'checked' appearance on the *next* rerender, eg. a second click.

Why is that? Isn't it the point of controlled components to work independently from browser events?

Someone explaining this to me would definitely ease the pain of hours spent boiling down my complex use case. Thank you!

**Update**: Here's a quick [Codepen example](https://codepen.io/gl03/pen/Yzxgqqd) demonstrating the odd behaviour.
I included an 'unprevented checkbox' and one with a prevented `onClick` event as comparison.
Notice how the one with prevented `onChange` switches its appearance to its actual state as soon as I click a *different* checkbox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checkboxes behave a little differently.  As you likely know, the typical use case for `preventDefault()` is the `onSubmit()` function of a form where you will do your own AJAX call, and thus want to prevent the default form submission. But with checkboxe (and most inputs) there's a little more involved.

### Checked attribute

Per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox#attr-checked), the `checked` attribute is "A Boolean attribute indicating whether or not this checkbox is checked by default (when the page loads). It *does not* indicate whether this checkbox is currently checked: if the checkbox’s state is changed, this content attribute does not reflect the change." In a funny way then, there's a disconnect between the `checked` attribute, and whether or not the state of the input is checked or not. When it comes to React, on each rerender, the `checked` attribute will reflect the current state, but it's still only a default value in the sense that the input has been newly rendered, and not manipulated since the state last changed.

### Native `eventListener` for `<input type="checkbox" />`

Also, without getting too off track, the event that natively changes the state on a checkbox input is actually the `click` event, not the `change` event. If you were to mess with the listeners and the values of a checkbox input in your browser's js console, you'd see you could manipulate it in a way that the checkbox isn't checked, but the values of the node say otherwise.

### Possible solution

Based on the above, in this case you *don't want* to prevent the default behavior, because the default behavior on the `change` event doesn't conflict with what you want to do (and for some reason preventing it causes problems).  In fact, in the [Mozilla docs examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox#attr-checked), you'll notice they don't use `preventDefault()` when updating state on controlled components. I wish I had a better understanding of *exactly why* adding `preventDefault()` to change handlers for inputs causes problems like this, but hopefully these few little tidbits give some more clarity.

Comment: Thank you, Dave. The fact that the `checked` attribute only describes the _default_ state on page load is a good lead. I still can't wrap my head around the actual behaviour (updating appearance on a _second_ click - see my [Codepen example](https://codepen.io/gl03/pen/Yzxgqqd) above), but I guess the reasons for that are buried deep in the interfacing of react and browser events. Perhaps a stone better left unturned. ;)

Answer (score -1):

Try moving `event.preventDefault()` above `this.setState` line.

Comment: thank you for the wild guess, but this does not make a difference. c.f. MDN: "Calling preventDefault() [during any stage of event flow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault#notes) cancels the event, meaning that any default action normally taken by the implementation as a result of the event will not occur."